# Lucene.net is throwing Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy.MergeException after flushing IndexWriter 100 times

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am trying to create Lucene.net index, Which will be updated (add and update new documents) after every 3 to 5 days. In the following code i am just showing the running code example.

In the code after running the loop 100 times, `indexWriter.Flush(true, true, true)` on fifth last line throw exception `Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy.MergeException` with an inner exception `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`.

After this every time `indexWriter.Flush` throw this exception. Which means i cannot update the index after updating it 100 times.

```
for (int outer = 0; outer < 200; outer++)
{
    IndexWriter indexWriter = null;
    while (indexWriter == null)
    {
        try
        {
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30),
                !IndexReader.IndexExists(directory),
                new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH));
        }
        catch (LockObtainFailedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lock is taken, waiting for timeout...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("IndexWriter lock obtained, this process has exclusive write access to index");
    indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(500);

    for (int iDoc = 0; iDoc < 100; iDoc++)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("id", DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString(), Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
        doc.Add(new Field("Title", "dog " + GeneratePhrase(50), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
            Field.TermVector.NO));
        doc.Add(new Field("Body", "dog " + GeneratePhrase(50), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
            Field.TermVector.NO));
        indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total docs is {0}", indexWriter.NumDocs());

    Console.WriteLine("Flushing and disposing writer...");
    indexWriter.Flush(true, true, true);
    indexWriter.Commit();
    indexWriter.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code or we can update this policy or any other fix?

I am using Lucene.net 3.0.3

Comment: Your code is not *updating*, it is *adding*. I believe you should be calling `indexWriter.UpdateDocument()` instead of `indexWriter.AddDocument()`. That doesn't mean this isn't a bug, though. Another thing you could try is upgrading to 4.8.0 beta to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: My application is written in .net 4, I have to support Windows XP. I cannot switch to Lucene.net 4.8 because it is written for .net 4.5.1

Comment: I think you don't need `GC.Collect()` here. Also you could use the construct `using(...) {..}` to also eliminate the line `indexWriter.Dispose()` Probably just a matter of preference.